# elasticsearch-js Update document with upsert and params

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have documents having one field : numberReqs
when I execute :

```js
client.update({
  index: 'index',
  type: 'type',
  id: 'id',
  body: {
    script: "def docSrc = ctx._source; docSrc.numberReqs+=nubmerReqsToAdd;",
    params: {
      nubmerReqsToAdd: 1
    },
    upsert: {
      numberReqs: 0
    }
  }
}, (err) => { console.log(err) })
```

This code throws document_missing_exception even if I mentioned the upsert.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the parameters inside the 'doc' object and use

> doc_as_upsert: true

in the body.

```
client.update({
 index: 'index',
 type: 'type',
 id: 'id',
 body: {
  doc: {
   key: value
  },
 doc_as_upsert: true
 }
}, (err) => { console.log(err) })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the goal here is to execute a script when the document exists (increment, calculate ...), the docs says : update a document with a script or initialize it, when the document does not exist.

Comment: To resume, I need to write this request with js : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts ( the first example )

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell ES to do an upsert

```js
client.update({
  index: 'index',
  type: 'type',
  id: 'id',
  body: {
    script: "def docSrc = ctx._source; docSrc.numberReqs+=nubmerReqsToAdd;",
    params: {
      nubmerReqsToAdd: 1
    },
    scripted_upsert: true, 
    upsert: {
      numberReqs: 0
    }
  }
}, (err) => { console.log(err) })
```